# stack using linked list Implementation is not working

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm currently working on implementing a stack using a linked list (LIFO) in C. I had gone through some tutorials and also with some stack-overflow post and come up with following solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
   char string[20];
   struct node *next;
} node;

node *push(char *element, node *head);
node *pop(node *head);
void destroy_stack(node *p);

int main(void)
{


    // create new stack
    node *stack = NULL;

    // push 6 "functions" to the stack
    char *function[6] = {"first funct", "second funct", "third funct",
    "fourth funct", "fifth funct", "sixt funct"};       
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("function is : %s\n",function[i]);
        stack = push(function[i], stack);
        if (!stack)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Not enough memory space for new list");
            return 1;
        }
    }


    // display the stack
    for (node *temp = stack; temp != NULL; temp = temp -> next)
    {

        printf("Elements of the stack are: %s\n", temp -> string);
    }

    // pop the elements from the stack
    while (stack != NULL)
    {

        printf("Popped elemet is: %s\n", stack -> string);
        stack = pop(stack);


    }

    destroy_stack(stack);
    return 0;

} 

node *push(char *element, node *head)
{
    // create space for new element on stack
    node *temp = sizeof(node);
    if (!temp)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // if stack is empty
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        strcpy(temp -> string, element);
        temp -> next = NULL;
        return temp;
    }

    strcpy(temp -> string, element);
    temp -> next = head;
    return temp;
}

node *pop(node * head)
{
    // create a new head
    node *newHead = head->next;

    // pop the element from stack
    free(head);

    return newHead;

}

void destroy_stack(node *p)
{
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        destroy_stack(p -> next);
    }
    free(p);
}
```

But my code is not working and can't understand why this is happening dew to lack of C programming knowledge. Can anyone Help me with this please?

Comment: `- >` is wrong, it's `->` (without space between `-` and `>`).

Comment: oh parden me @Jabbberworcky i think this happens after i used a online beautifier to format my code...Had a warnning that my code is not properly formatted...i will fix that

Comment: Same for ` < stdio.h >` instead of ` <stdio.h>`, I'm not sure all compilers accept this

Comment: The question heading is wrong. It should be Implementation of stack using linked list.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake...I will update it

Comment: No problem. And another small note, when returning pointers, it is better to write as node* function() rather than node *function() :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
node * temp = sizeof(node);
```

Instead of allocating memory you just put the size of your node into the `temp` pointer which should trig a compiler warning.

it should be:

```
node * temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Didn't you get a compiler warning?

**Side note**

You shouln't use recursion in `destroy_stack`, a simple loop would do.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jabberwocky. I just used a online c compiler for the task..(Not much of C language fan)...I really appreciate your contribution towards me.

Answer (score 1):

You just messed up with the dynamic memory allocation in your `push` function. This must be corrected as follows.

```
node * temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Comment: Thank you @Aravinda.. I really appreciate your contribution towards me.